# how to get the strings and concat several strings to one string between two index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list looks like the following:

**content1,2,3... is the message, which can be anything**

```
lst1 = [
'2022-02-21 14:26:02 user1',
'content1',
'content2',
'content3',
'2022-02-24 14:40:12 user2',
'content11',
'content22',
'2022-02-25 14:26:02 user1',
'content12',
'2022-02-24 14:40:12 user2',
'content13'
]
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary which contains something like  `'2022-02-21 14:26:02 user1'` as the key and its content as corresponding values.

```
{
'2022-02-21 14:26:02 user1':'content1;content2;content3',
'2022-02-24 14:40:12 user2':'content11;content22',
'2022-02-25 14:26:02 user1':'content12',
'2022-02-24 14:40:12 user2':'content13'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need pandas here, a simple python loop would work:

```
d = {}
key = None
for x in lst1:
    if x[:4].isdigit():
        key = x
        continue
    if key in d:
        d[key] = d[key]+f';{x}'
    else:
        d[key] = x
```

output:

```
{'2022-02-21 14:26:02 user1': 'content1;content2;content3',
 '2022-02-24 14:40:12 user2': 'content11;content22;content13',
 '2022-02-25 14:26:02 user1': 'content12'}
```

Comment: Could you explain ```d[key] = d[key]+f';{x}'``` this line? Thanks!

Comment: This is a [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/), you could also use `d[key] = d[key]+';'+x'